# pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen can't locate the image

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm building a bot a to play the following game called Sushi Go Round. I was using function locateAllOnScreen to locate the orders.

The code is like following:

```
import pyautogui

onigiri = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('onigiri.png')

print(onigiri)
```

The onigiri.png was cropped out from the third customer. `locateAllOnScreen` could only locate the third customer's order but not the forth customer's even though their images (orders) were exactly the same.

1. Why didn't the function locate all images even though the images were the same?
2. Or were the images actually different?

I'm frustrated. Please help. Thank you very much!

Sushi Go Round

[image: Sushi Go Round]

onigiri.png

[image: onigiri.png]

Comment: Please write your code as ```Your Code``` to make it clear.

Comment: pyautogui should have also function to locate on image so you could check if it can find it. it has also option `confidence=` to control how indentical should be elements. See doc [screenshot](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)

Comment: when I test your code with your images then it finds one item. But when I use `confidence=0.9` then it finds 2 items. So images are little different - we may not see difference but for computer they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us (humans) images seem identical but for computer they are different if even single pixel is different.

If I use `confidence=0.9` then it finds two items.

```
import pyautogui

onigiri = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('onigiri.png', confidence=0.9)

for item in onigiri:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
Box(left=849, top=400, width=55, height=53)
Box(left=988, top=400, width=55, height=53)
```

---

Doc [Screenshot](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html):

```
The optional "confidence" keyword argument specifies the accuracy with 
which the function should locate the image on screen. This is helpful 
in case the function is not able to locate an image due to negligible 
pixel differences:
```

---

For other users:

[Programming a Bot to Play the "Sushi Go Round" Flash Game - The Invent with Python Blog](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/)

Comment: Thank you very much. The code finds the images properly now. Thank you.